# How can I report a product fault to Microsoft?

Tags: report

I have a Logitech Headset that uses MS Supplied drivers, in this case Generic USBAudio Driver.
The sound is really choppy in a 64bit version of Win 7. 32Bit works perfectly fine.

How is it possible for me to notify MS, and get the problem fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Microsoft [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) to report bugs and feature requests.

Comment: Although that's no guarantee you'll get your problem fixed

Answer (score 2):

There's a [Contact Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/contactus/?ws=support) link on [support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/).

There's a lot of information on that site, I'd search that as my first option - you never know they might already know about the issue and have posted a patch.